# After upgrading hadoop clusters to clodera 4 b1 ,Invalid "mapreduce.jobtracker.address" configuration error comes

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I recently upgraded to clodera4b1 .Before upgradation the mapreduce jobs were running fine but now when I execute any mapreduce program,Thefollowing error comes:

Command run:

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-0.23.0-cdh4b1.jar grep *.xml /user/out/ 'dfs'


12/04/10 19:23:15 INFO mapreduce.Cluster: Failed to use org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalClientProtocolProvider due to error: Invalid "mapreduce.jobtracker.address" configuration value for LocalJobRunner : "dev-xxx:yyyy"
12/04/10 19:23:15 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:anchauhan (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.initialize(Cluster.java:123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1181)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1167)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.connect(Job.java:1180)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1233)
    at com.nextag.mapred.MerchantImport.doTask(MerchantImport.java:221)
    at com.nextag.mapred.Main.main(Main.java:9)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:200)
```

And for my custom mapred jobs,I changed the library files to the new ones while compiling jar files,but no success

Comment: what's the value of `mapreduce.jobtracker.address` in your CDH4 `conf/mapred-site.xml` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had the same exception and the reason was that we had the wrong dependencies in the pom files. We were pointing to hadoop-client version 2.0.0-cdh4.0.0 which is for yarn but we are using MRv1 so we should have been pointing to 2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.0.0. You should not have any yarn jar files in your dependencies.

[Reference](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/cdh/5-0-x/CDH-Version-and-Packaging-Information/cdhvd_hadoop_api_dependencies.html)